# Winforms GUI (grids, chkboxlists) design approach

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

I have an app using Devexpress controls, xtragrids and chkboxlists

I have a dataset containing few tables, some of whose data goes to grid and some to list.

List data is dependent on grid row selection.

I load the whole dataset from DB (not very large) at start once, then use it as cache for GUI.

I need to have Add/Edit/Delete functionality for grid and list of items (include/exclude pattern).

Should i maintain my own structure to hold the changes, and should i manually recreate and change dataSource whenever there is edit ?

Or is going through dataSet acceptchanges is better (not touching DataSource again).

And how to approach the DB update ? DbAdapter.UpdateChanges ? is it good way or what is the standard pattern.

**EDIT**

Not fully sure, but is it ont he lines of MVC MVVM patterns ?

Comment: why not let xtragrid take care of it?? (that's not the point when using a control like that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its better 'not' to edit operations on the grid itself. Not a good user experience. And most of the times its not possible to display all the columns in the grid. They are just too many.

You can easily attach a [Property Grid Control](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraVerticalGridPropertyGridControltopic) to a gridrow.

When a user clicks on a row, the PGC will load the row data automatically.

I would suggest having three buttons Save/New/Delete below the PGC. Each button tied to a stored procedure call in database.

Comment: Op is using devexpress xtragrid. The user experience is totally different on that grid comparing it to the standard one. I even don't see the question, when using those controls is totally different from the standard ones.

Comment: OP also asked about whether its a good way/what is the standard pattern. What ever grid it may be, it is not good to have automatic edits to db whenever row focus changes.